# Trouble with top down recursive algorithm

Tags: python, search, recursion

I am trying to make word chains, but cant get around recursive searching. 
I want to return a list of the words reuired to get to the target word
get_words_quicker returns a list of words that can be made by just changing one letter.

```
def dig(InWord, OutWord, Depth):
    if Depth == 0:
        return False
    else:
        d = Depth - 1;
    wordC = 0;
    wordS = [];
    for q in get_words_quicker(InWord):
        wordC+=1
        if(OutWord == q):
            return q
        wordS.append(q)

    for i in range(0,wordC):
        return dig(wordS[i],OutWord,d)
```

Any help/questions would be much appreciated.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: `for i in range(...): return ...` is fundamentally broken - that loop can never iterate more than once - and if it iterates zero times, you fall off the bottom without returning anything.

Answer (score 0):

**ANALYSIS**

There is nowhere in your code that you form a list *to return*.  The one place where you make a list is appending to wordS, but you never return this list, and your recursive call passes only one element (a single word) from that list.

As jasonharper already pointed out, your final loop can iterate once and return whatever the recursion gives it, or it can fall off the end and return **None** (rather than "nothing").

You have two other returns in the code: one returns **False**, and the other will return **q**, but only if q has the same value as **OutWord**.

Since there is no code where you use the result or alter the return value in any way, the only possibilities for your code's return value are **None**, **False**, and **OutWord**.

REPAIR

I'm afraid that I'm not sure how to fix this routine *your* way, since you haven't really described how you intended this code to carry out the high-level tasks you describe.  The abbreviated variable names hide their purposes.  **wordC** is a counter whose only function is to hold the length of the list returned from **get_words_quicker** -- which could be done much more easily.

If you can clean up the code, improve the data flow and/or documentation to something that shows only one or two disruptions in logic, perhaps we can fix the remaining problems.  As it stands, I hesitate to try -- you'd have *my* solution, not *yours*.